# We are passing AuthorizationUrl inside <script type="application/json" id="amp-subscriptions"> but the api call is not being made

Tags: amp-html

This is the script tag inside which I am passing a JSON object with all the required fields. I am expecting an api call to be made to https://pub.com/amp-authorisation?rid=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL. But I don't see any api call in the network tab. Am I missing Something or doing something wrong?

```
<script data-react-helmet="true" type="application/json" id="amp-subscriptions">{
            "services": [
              {
                "authorizationUrl": "https://pub.com/amp-authorisation?rid=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL",
                "pingbackUrl": "https://pub.com/amp-pingback?rid=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL",
                "actions": {
                  "login": "https://pub.com/amp-login?rid=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL",
                  "subscribe": "https://pub.com/amp-subscribe?rid=READER_ID&url=SOURCE_URL"
                }
              },
            ],
            "score": {
              "supportsViewer": 10,
              "isReadyToPay": 9
            },
            "fallbackEntitlement": {
              "source": "fallback",
              "granted": true,
              "grantReason": "SUBSCRIBER",
              "data": {
                "isLoggedIn": false
              }
            }
          }</script>
```

I have gone through the documentation and seen

````
Authorization is an endpoint provided by the Publisher and called by the AMP Runtime. It is a credentialed CORS GET endpoint.

The Authorization endpoint must implement the security protocol described in CORS security in AMP.
``` but not sure If this is where the problem exists and if yes how to implement that
````